# User defined MySQL variable in EJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to call a query through EJS / Express. This works in MySQL directly but not through Express / EJS.

I have a working query in MySQL, which is unrecognised when I try to run through Express.

```
'SET @cumulative:=0; \
select * from ( \
 select str_to_date(dateAndTime,\'%Y-%m-%d %T\') AS 
dateAndTime,description,chargeId,amount,(@cumulative := @cumulative + 
amount) AS cumulative \
from charges \
WHERE chargeStatus = "succeeded" AND 
DATE_ADD(str_to_date(dateAndTime,\'%Y-%m-%d\'), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) = 
CURDATE() \
order by str_to_date(dateAndTime,\'%Y-%m-%d %T\') \
) AS T1 order by cumulative desc'
```

Why does this query work in MySQL eg, Workbench directly but not when called through Express / Node?

The below is my node module.

Also, removing the line `'SET @cumulative:=0; \` results in success (with a missing result field, cumulative.)

```
var db = require('../db/db');

var queryString = 'select * from ( \
select str_to_date(dateAndTime,"%Y-%m-%d %T") AS dateAndTime,description,chargeId,amount,(@cumulative := @cumulative + amount) AS cumulative \
from charges \
WHERE chargeStatus = "succeeded" AND DATE_ADD(str_to_date(dateAndTime,"%Y-%m-%d"), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) = CURDATE() \
order by str_to_date(dateAndTime,"%Y-%m-%d %T") \
) AS T1 order by cumulative desc';



module.exports = {
    home: function(req, res){
        db.query(queryString,function(err,result){
          if(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
          if(result===undefined){
            res.send('No results')
          }
          else{
            res.render('home',{result:result});
          }

        });
    },
};
```

Comment: You need to show us how you execute this. Right now this a confusingly escaped SQL string. Tip: If using single quotes in your query, use double quotes to define it.

Comment: @tadman thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL driver only supports executing *one query statement at a time* so you must split this up into two different queries.

It's worth noting that `async` and Promises makes this code way easier to write. In effect you're looking for:

```
await db.query("SET @cumulative:=0");
let result = await db.query("SELECT ...");
```

The MySQL command-line shell has a sophisticated statement parser that looks for the "delimiter character", usually `;` but that can be changed, in order to split up statements for execution. The MySQL driver for Node, like most drivers, does not support this.

Comment: Excellent thank you. That resolves this issue in super fast time too. Am making a journey into ES6 at the moment so your extra comments are super helpful.

Comment: ES6 is a tectonic shift away from the old callback chaining model and if your environment supports Promises I'd strongly encourage using them whenever possible.